# What is a good word for "a group of intellectuals" or "a group of smart learners"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What could be a good word for *a group of intellectuals* or *a group of smart learners*? Any suggestions of related terms also invited.

I am looking forward to rename *groups* in a social application with somewhat more fitting word.

Thanks in anticipation of your great suggestions.